# Significato di prestazione

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, phrase-request, single-words

Buongiorno,

Ho ricevuto una lettera con della terminologia burocratica e non sono riuscito a capire tramite dizionario se la parola prestazione avesse il significato di somma di denaro o versamento. Qualcuno mi potrebbe aiutare?

Il testo dice:

> Sulla base della presente riliquidazione gli importi della prestazione
>   relativi al corrente anno, già comunicato con un precedente
>   provvedimento di liquidazione sono così cambiati
>
> Prestazione lorda: ...
>  Indennità: ...
>  Prestazione al netto
>   delle trattenute: ...

Sinceramente non ci capisco molto, e neppure capisco la differenza tra le tre voci riportate in basso come *indennità* e *trattenute*.

Grazie per il vostro aiuto.

Comment: Detto in modo molto informale, una “prestazione” è “qualcosa che hai fatto”: un lavoro, una missione, un incarico portato a termine (anche se qui sembra che lo usino anche per indicare il compenso di quella prestazione). A che cosa si riferisca di preciso, lo puoi sapere solo tu.

Comment: Sì, infatti si tratta di una lettera riguardante un assegno di invalidità che sto cercando di capire. La persona a cui è indirizzata, essendo invalida, non ha eseguito nessuna particolare prestazione, per ottenere la somma mensile di denaro che riceve. Quindi, com'è possibile che appaia la voce "prestazione" in questa lettera?

Comment: Può essere che abbia _ricevuto_ qualche prestazione (spesso si usa per visite o interventi medici)?

Answer (score 3):

Su Treccani la [prestazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/prestazione) viene definita come:

> La p. consiste in un comportamento cui il debitore è tenuto, tanto nel
>   caso in cui derivi da una dichiarazione negoziale di volontà della
>   parte o delle parti, quanto nel caso in cui nasca da un mero fatto cui
>   la legge riconnette determinati effetti obbligatori

Ed inoltre:

> La p. può essere determinata in natura o in denaro, o – più
>   esattamente – può essere di specie o di genere. P. tipiche in natura o
>   di specie sono quelle di consegnare una cosa determinata o di fare.

Nel tuo caso sembra riferirsi ad una pensione (vista la presenza del termine riliquidazione), o in generale ad una somma, un’erogazione in denaro da parte di un ente della Pubblica Amministrazione, quali ad esempio INPS, INAIL, etc.

La *prestazione lorda* è quella comprensiva delle tasse mentre la *prestazione netta* è la somma di denaro che viene effettivamente accreditata.

L’[indennità](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/indennita) come da definizione Treccani è:

> **indennità** Corrispettivo stabilito in favore di chi, per interessi
>   generali, subisce il sacrificio di un diritto. Attribuzione
>   patrimoniale dell'imprenditore al prestatore di lavoro, non avente
>   carattere retributivo e corrisposta a titolo di rimborso di spese o
>   per speciali oneri o disagi sopportati dal prestatore a causa o in
>   occasione della prestazione di lavoro (i. di trasferta, i. di rischi,
>   i. di servizio).

Le [trattenute](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trattenuta_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) sono le tasse applicate alla prestazione:

> **trattenuta** s. f. [part. pass. femm. di trattenere]. - (amministr.)
>   [somma detratta dallo stipendio del lavoratore per essere versata come
>   imposta o contributo] ≈ ritenuta. ‖ decurtazione, deduzione,
>   detrazione.

Comment: Mi potresti per favore aiutare a capire anche le parole del dizionario? "comportamento cui il debitore è tenuto". Non capisco la struttura grammaticale di queste parole e il loro significato. Me le potresti spiegare un po' alla volta, per favore. Scusami, ma sono molto carente in italiano, non essendo la lingua nella quale si esprimermi meglio.

Comment: Significa comportamento al quale il debitore deve aderire per forza?

Comment: Il debitore dev'essere la persona tenuta a pagare detto soldi. In questo caso, si riferisce allo stato?

Comment: Inoltre, vorrei sapere, cosa significa in questo contesto, nella spiegazione dal dizionario, "in natura". Cioè, se non in denaro, allora come?

Comment: Se vuoi possiamo spostare la discussione sulla [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11367/bar-sport)...